# Flipping a 2D array matrix horizontally

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find an alternative solution for the classic question:

Given an m x n 2D image matrix where each integer represents a pixel. Flip it in-place along its horizontal axis.

Before:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

After:

```
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3
```

I know the classic solution, but was wondering if you could solve it by picturing the matrix turned clock-wise? Then, you could hypothetically just do a vertical flip on the matrix like below.

After turning:

```
3 6 9
2 5 8
1 4 7
```

```
public static void flipHorizontalAxis(int[][] matrix) 
{   
    for (int column = matrix.length - 1; column > 0; column--)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix[0].length / 2; row++)
        {
            int temp = matrix[column][row];
            matrix[column][row] = matrix[column][matrix.length - 1];
            matrix[column][matrix[0].length - 1] = temp;

            System.out.print(matrix[column][row] + "\t");
        }
            System.out.println();
    }

}
```

This is what I have so far but my output is showing:

```
3 4 7 
2 5 8
1 6 9
```

What is causing the error in my solution?

Comment: You are indeed right. Rotating and transposing a matrix will result in mirroring the matrix. The field of mathematics that researches such things is called Group Theory.

Comment: Please first modify the matrix, then print it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the classic solution and how simple it is, i.e. the simple flipping of rows, why would you even begin to consider any solution that has to process individual cells? That would be a waste of processing power and add unnecessary code complexity.

```
public static void flipHorizontalAxis(int[][] matrix) {
    int last = matrix.length - 1;
    for (int i = last / 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        int[] temp = matrix[i];
        matrix[i] = matrix[last - i];
        matrix[last - i] = temp;
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
int[][] matrix = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
flipHorizontalAxis(matrix);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```

*Output*

```
[[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: As far as I understood (although admittedly, it's not entirely clear...) the intention is exactly *not* to flip the matrix, but to rotate it. Maybe even to cover the full https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_8 ...

Comment: @Marco13 To add on to your point, I'm not moving any rows or columns from their original positions. I'm essentially viewing the matrix turned like this [column][row] instead of [row][column]. Meaning, at [2][0] = 3. [1][0] = 2 [0][0] = 1